# calculator: variable somehow undefined in "if else" statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, undefined, calculator

I'm trying to make a calculator with Javascript.
I have a function that asks to input an operator.
I want it to ask for an operator again if the user enters anything else than *, /, + or -.
Everything works fine if the user enters one of the accepted operators, however, if the wrong operator has been entered, and the function is executed for a second time, the value of the operator is somehow "undefined". And I am not sure why... When I call the function within the if statement, does it not jump back to the beginning of getOperator(), where I assign a value to the operator variable?
Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

```
function getOperator() {
    var operator = getStringInputWithPrompt('Please enter the operator:');
    if ((operator !== "+") && (operator !== "*") && (operator !== "-") && (operator !== "/")) {
        console.log("\nSorry that was not a valid operator");
        getOperator();
    } else {
    return operator;  
    }
}
```

Comment: Well if the input would for example be a letter, then it wouldn't equal *, +, _ or / at the same time, would it? 
Please correct me if I'm wrong! It worked with the code as I wrote it (I mean the if condition part of it worked), but if there's a better/shorter way to write it I'd love to know!

Comment: `!['+', '*', '-', '/'].includes(operator)`, or `!{ '+': true, '*': true, '-': true, '/': true }[operator]`

Comment: Aah great! I thought there would be a shorter way to write this that I wasn't aware of! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the result of the recursive calling.

```js
function getOperator() {
    var operator = prompt('Please enter the operator:');
    if (operator !== "+" && operator !== "*" && operator !== "-" && operator !== "/") {
        console.log("\nSorry that was not a valid operator");
        return getOperator();
    } else {
        return operator;
    }
}

console.log(getOperator());
```

Because of writing a calculator, you could use an object for the operators and check if the operator exist and take the function for this operator.

```js
const
    operators = {
        '+': (a, b) => a + b,
        '-': (a, b) => a - b,
        '*': (a, b) => a * b,
        '/': (a, b) => a / b
    };

function getOperator() {
    let operator = prompt('Please enter the operator:');
    if (operator in operators) return operator;
    return getOperator();                                // omit else after return
}

console.log(getOperator());
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside the `if`, you make a recursive call to `getOperator()` but you don't do anything with its returned value. You can return it immediately.

```
console.log("\nSorry that was not a valid operator");
return getOperator();
```